# Simple Service Locator

Tags: c#, .net, reinventing-the-wheel

I've created a small, strongly-typed generic Service Locator object for .NET 3.5.

It supports optional polymorphic service location and keyed services. I am looking for a general review, but especially looking for pointers on best practices I've missed or any awkwardness in the API.

This code can also be found as a [public GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Udellgames/servicer)

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple service locator
/// </summary>
public class ServiceLocator
{
    #region Private Classes

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple .NET 3.5 Tuple class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the first item.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="V">The type of the second item.</typeparam>
    [DebuggerDisplay("Item1: {Item1}, Item2: {Item2}")]
    private class Tuple<T, V>
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public T Item1 { get; set; }

        public V Item2 { get; set; }

        #endregion Public Properties

        #region Public Constructors

        public Tuple(T item1, V item2)
        {
            Item1 = item1;
            Item2 = item2;
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Object" />, is equal to this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="System.Object" /> to compare with this instance.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///   <c>true</c> if the specified <see cref="System.Object" /> is equal to this instance; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var objAsTuple = obj as Tuple<T, V>;
            return objAsTuple != null && IsEqualTo(objAsTuple.Item1, Item1) && IsEqualTo(objAsTuple.Item2, Item2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a hash code for this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A hash code for this instance, suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures like a hash table.
        /// </returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var item1HashCode = Item1 == null ? 0 : Item1.GetHashCode();
                var item2HashCode = Item2 == null ? 0 : Item2.GetHashCode();
                return item1HashCode + item2HashCode;
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the first object is equal to the second object, including if they are both null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second.</param>
        /// <returns>True if both first and second are null or first is equal to second.</returns>
        private bool IsEqualTo(object first, object second)
        {
            return first == null ? second == null : first.Equals(second);
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }

    #endregion Private Classes

    #region Private Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The instance for the Singleton pattern.
    /// </summary>
    private static ServiceLocator instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// The services
    /// </summary>
    private IDictionary<Tuple<Type, object>, object> services = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, object>, object>();

    #endregion Private Fields

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="ServiceLocator"/> is explicit.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This property controls how the ServiceLocator handles not being able to find a service of the requested type.
    /// If explicit is set to false, the ServiceLocator will look for services that can be casted to the requested type.
    /// If explicit is set to true, the ServiceLocator while throw an exception if it cannot find an exact match to the requested service.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if explicit; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public static bool Explicit { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Private Properties

    private static ServiceLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new ServiceLocator();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Properties

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears this instance by removing all services.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Clear()
    {
        ServiceLocator.Instance.services.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a service of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of service to get.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The instance of type T registered with the Service Locator.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="KeyNotFoundException">Thrown when the Service Locator cannot find an un-keyed service of the requested type and Explicit is true, or when the Service Locator cannot find an un-keyed service of the requested type or any type that can be assigned to the requested type and Explicit is false.</exception>
    public static T GetService<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetService<T>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the service using a key object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of service to get.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key to filter multiple services of the same type by.</param>
    /// <returns>The instance of type T registered with the provided key in the Service Locator.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.KeyNotFoundException">Thrown when the Service Locator cannot find an a service of the requested type with a matching key and Explicit is true, or when the Service Locator cannot find a service of the requested type or any type that can be assigned to the requested type with the matching key and Explicit is false.</exception>
    public static T GetService<T>(object key) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(type, key);

        if (!Instance.services.ContainsKey(dictKey))
        {
            if (!Explicit)
            {
                var subTypeKey = Instance.services.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                    (key == null ? x.Item2 == null : key.Equals(x.Item2))
                    && type.IsAssignableFrom(x.Item1));

                if (subTypeKey != null)
                {
                    return (T)Instance.services[subTypeKey];
                }
            }

            throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Cannot get a value for type: {0} and key: {1}. That type has not been registered yet.", type, key));
        }

        return (T)Instance.services[dictKey];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the specified service with no key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the service.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="service">The service.</param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">>Thrown when a service of this type has already been registered without a key.</exception>
    public static void Register<T>(T service) where T : class
    {
        Register(service, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the specified service with a key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of service.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="service">The service.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown when a service of this type has already been registered with this key.</exception>
    public static void Register<T>(T service, object key) where T : class
    {
        var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(typeof(T), key);

        if (Instance.services.ContainsKey(dictKey))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot register an item of type: {0} and key: {1}. That type is already registered.", dictKey.Item1, key));
        }
        else
        {
            Instance.services.Add(dictKey, service);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregisters the specified un-keyed service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of service.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="service">The service.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException">Thrown when the given service and key are not registered to this ServiceLocator.</exception>
    public static void Unregister<T>(T service) where T : class
    {
        Unregister(service, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unregisters the specified keyed service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of service.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="service">The service.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException">Thrown when the given service and key are not registered to this ServiceLocator.</exception>
    public static void Unregister<T>(T service, object key) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(type, key);

        if (!Instance.services.ContainsKey(dictKey))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Could not find a service of type {0} with key {1}", type, key));
        }

        Instance.services.Remove(dictKey);
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Regions**

Please read [are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)

> Is there a good use for regions?
>
> No. There was a legacy use: generated code. Still, code generation
>   tools just have to use partial classes instead. If C# has regions
>   support, it's mostly because this legacy use, and because now that too
>   many people used regions in their code, it would be impossible to
>   remove them without breaking existent codebases.
>
> Think about it as about goto. The fact that the language or the IDE
>   supports a feature doesn't mean that it should be used daily. StyleCop
>   SA1124 rule is clear: you should not use regions. Never.

---

Instead of using the `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` method you should better use [`TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Please see: [what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382740/2655508)

> TryGetValue will be faster.
>
> ContainsKey uses the same check as TryGetValue, which internally
>   refers to the actual entry location. The Item property actually has
>   nearly identical code functionality as TryGetValue, except that it
>   will throw an exception instead of returning false.
>
> Using ContainsKey followed by the item basically duplicates the lookup
>   functionality, which is the bulk of the computation in this case.

---

In the `Unregiser()` method

> ```
> public static void Unregister<T>(T service, object key) where T : class
> {
>     var type = typeof(T);
>     var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(type, key);
>
>     if (!Instance.services.ContainsKey(dictKey))
>     {
>         throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Could not find a service of type {0} with key {1}", type, key));
>     }
>
>     Instance.services.Remove(dictKey);
> }
> ```

you should remove the `ContainsKey()` call and use the returned value of the [`Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call instead like so

```
public static void Unregister<T>(T service, object key) where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(type, key);

    if (Instance.services.Remove(dictKey)) { return; }

    throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Could not find a service of type {0} with key {1}", type, key));
}
```

**Conclusion**

Setting aside the points mentioned above:

- your xml documentations looks pretty good, I couldn't find any flaw in them (quick glance).
- your code is well structured and readable

---

Answer (score 5):

Some quick remarks:

- Remove the regions. They're [an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53114/123339) basically, and you certainly shouldn't need them with code that's less than 250 lines long.
- Your singleton implementation is [not liked by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).
- Don't use `ContainsKey`. If you need to get something from an `IDictionary`, use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639(v=vs.90).aspx) instead.

So `GetService` would become this:

```
public static T GetService<T>(object key) where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var dictKey = new Tuple<Type, object>(type, key);
    object returnValue;

    if(Instance.services.TryGetValue(dictKey, out returnValue))
    {
        return (T)returnValue;
    }

    if (!Explicit)
    {
        var subTypeKey = Instance.services.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            (key == null ? x.Item2 == null : key.Equals(x.Item2))
            && type.IsAssignableFrom(x.Item1));

        if (subTypeKey != null)
        {
            return (T)Instance.services[subTypeKey];
        }
    }

    throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Cannot get a value for type: {0} and key: {1}. That type has not been registered yet.", type, key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I hate regions too, but thought I might have been in the minority since everybody at my workplace loves them. Since I seem to (gladly) be wrong, I'll remove them from the repository now.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are spot-on regarding the operation of the service locator itself. I'd like to take a moment to regard the `Tuple` class. Based on its usage, it should be made immutable. That, and, it should be interface-based for ease of unit testing of the service locator independent of anything else. So let's do so:

```
    private interface ITuple<T, V>
    {
        T Item1 { get; }

        V Item2 { get; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple .NET 3.5 Tuple class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the first item.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="V">The type of the second item.</typeparam>
    [DebuggerDisplay("Item1: {Item1}, Item2: {Item2}")]
    private sealed class Tuple<T, V> : ITuple<T, V>
    {
        private readonly T _Item1;

        private readonly V _Item2;

        public Tuple(T item1, V item2)
        {
            this._Item1 = item1;
            this._Item2 = item2;
        }

        public T Item1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Item1;
            }
        }

        public V Item2
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Item2;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Object" />, is equal to this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="System.Object" /> to compare with this instance.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///   <c>true</c> if the specified <see cref="System.Object" /> is equal to this instance; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var objAsTuple = obj as Tuple<T, V>;
            return objAsTuple != null && IsEqualTo(objAsTuple.Item1, this._Item1) && IsEqualTo(objAsTuple.Item2, this._Item2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a hash code for this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A hash code for this instance, suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures like a hash table.
        /// </returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var item1HashCode = this._Item1 == null ? 0 : this._Item1.GetHashCode();
                var item2HashCode = this._Item2 == null ? 0 : this._Item2.GetHashCode();
                return item1HashCode + item2HashCode;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the first object is equal to the second object, including if they are both null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second.</param>
        /// <returns>True if both first and second are null or first is equal to second.</returns>
        private static bool IsEqualTo(object first, object second)
        {
            return first == null ? second == null : first.Equals(second);
        }
    }
```

Let's also create a factory class which returns new instances of the tuple.

```
    private static class Tuple
    {
        public static ITuple<T, V> Create<T, V>(T item1, V item2)
        {
            return new Tuple<T, V>(item1, item2);
        }
    }
```

Now, use `ITuple<,>` in your code where you currently use `Tuple<,>` and instead of `new Tuple<Type, object>(...)` you'd use `Tuple.Create(...)`.

Comment: Very good idea.

Comment: I'm unsure how much extracting an interface for my `Tuple` implementation helps with regards to unit testing here. `Tuple` is used entirely internally (and hidden away from Service Locator users). There is no method for accessing or changing the internal `Tuple` representation, and I am certain such a method would be TMI for users. As such I'm not even sure *how* I'd mock it, let alone *why* I'd want to. Great point on immutability though!